# Adding a custom button and sharing records

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule

I am having a problem implementing a requirement. I have an object called Credentials and this credential object have two fields name and password.

**Now, the requirement is, a user called Manager should see a Share button on the top of a Credential detail record and if the Manager clicks on share button then the manager should be able to share that record to any other user called consumer.**

Now if that consumer user login then the consumer should see the shared record. If the manager removes already shared record then consumer should not see that record.

Any ideas on implementing this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

First of all , you have to make credentials object "Private" from sharing setting. Then give "Modify All" permission to manager. After that your scenario will work automatically.